# Use of Orbot on Mobile

Tags: orbot, mobile

I read that using Personal Accounts like Gmail, Facebook etc (with real Personal Information) on Tor is not anonymous or safe.
So if I installed Orbot on un-rooted android mobile then even I browse anonymously using Orweb, but the other apps like my Email Client, Stackexchange app or even Play Store itself on my phone does/can connect to internet using my external IP (the real one). Doesn't it reveal my identity??
I am using "NoRoot Firewall" (noroot firewall is an app for un-rooted android devices which block or allow internet access to certain devices by creating a virtual VPN) for blocking internet access of some apps but running Torand Noroot Firewall simultanously makes a bigger mess (running simultanously Orweb shows You are not connected to Tor even when Orbot saying you are connected to Tor i.e. may be orweb connects directly to internet with my real IP address).
I also tried edit my mobile APN setting to local host and 8118, but may be that allowing all apps to connect through Tor including Gmail account via Email Client.

So how can I use Tor on android while blocking internet access to other apps like email client and other apps which use my real identity?
Is there any other option other than rooting my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they often mean with that is that information can still be gathered from your connection, 
when the data you send\receive goes out from a exit node it can then be sniffed \ logged by the exit node, this goes for unencrypted data (non-https connections).

It does hide your IP - but you have to be careful about what information you can reveal in the other end by logging in to these services and using untrusted connections\web services and so on.

There is more detailed information about the exit node sniffing issue here:

https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#CanExitNodesEavesdrop

And about anonymity here:

https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#AmITotallyAnonymous